# How do I set ionic serve to use Chrome as the default browser?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to run `ionic serve` with Google Chrome.

I've tried:

```
ionic serve --browser chrome
ionic serve --browser google-chrome
```

But that doesn't work. I can get it to use firefox if I type:

```
ionic serve --browser firefox
```

How do I set the default browser for `ionic serve` to Chrome?

Comment: set chrome as default browser..for system!

Comment: Hi mahasagar , Chrome is default browser for system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ionic.project` file add:

```
"defaultBrowser": ""
```

OR

```
"defaultBrowser": "chrome"
```

and try `ionic serve`

this is working..!

u can also try :

```
"defaultBrowser": "firefox"
```

[this..](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-browser-chrome-not-working-on-osx/27223) and [this..](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/328) might be help..

Comment: While adding "defaultBrowser": "" to ionic.project  it takes default browser as Firefox , while adding "defaultBrowser": "chrome" not working

Comment: Hi mahasagar , Its Working on all other Applications , It seems something missing in one of the my application i will check it out.

Comment: Hi. this is no longer working for ionic 2 (no ionic.project file, ionic.config.json doesnt accept), the option ionic serve -w chrome as mentioned below works for ionic 2. Not sure if it still works for Ionic 1

Answer (score 16):

On Mac, option `-f chrome` is not working, on ionic version 2.1.8

Use `ionic serve --browser "google chrome"`

It will set the default browser to Chrome.

Comment: Thank, this is worked for me :  ionic serve --lab --browser chrome

Answer (score 7):

Try `ionic serve -w chrome`, this will serve ionic2 in `Chrome` (ionic2 RC4+)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me too. When I open chrome manually I can access http://localhost:8100/ , but ionic is not opening chrome itself when starting from the cli

Comment: @bastifix which version of ionic you are using? run `ionic info` when you are in your project folder

Comment: Nice Working for me

Comment: I'm using
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.5
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0

but I also not able/knowing how to update to ionic 2 final

Comment: @bastifix usually I update my ionic globally by `npm`, then I create a new project, then I compare `package.json` of new project with mine, and I fix the versions in my project, and I add if something is new , then I do `npm install` in my project

Answer (score 4):

Try `ionic serve -f chrome`. This will set default ionic browser to Chrome and subsequent `ionic serve` commands will run in Chrome.

Comment: Just do be sure, you do have Chrom installed?

Comment: Yes I have installed Latest version of Google Chrome

Comment: It is not working in a particular Application , but works fine in all other applications , Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

As of working in Ionic v3.9.2, you can open this using

```
$ionic lab --browser chrome
```

command to open the app in Google Chrome by default.

Answer (score 2):

**ionic serve -w chrome**
this works for me and successfully launch my app on chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
cordova run browser -- --port=8001 --target=Firefox
```

OR

```
cordova run browser --target=Firefox
```

OR

```
cordova run browser  --target=Chrome
```

OR

```
cordova run browser -- --port=8001 --target=Chrome
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 3 and mac you need to type like this:
ionic serve -w "Google Chrome"

Answer (score 0):

The following will work in **Windows** when anyone face issue in **ionic serve -f chrome**:

`ionic serve --browser "chrome"`

Answer (score 0):

And this works on my Mac:

`ionic serve --browser "google chrome"`

Answer (score -1):

you can try with these commands when you fire up your app

```
ionic serve --browser "google chrome"

ionic serve --browser "safari"

ionic serve --browser "firefox"
```