# Ionic serve change default browser

Tags: ionic-framework

I am running Windows 10 Pro. My default browser for Windows is Google Chrome. I am also running visual studio code (version 1.22.1).

When I type a command in the terminal (git bash) which opens the browser, for example `ionic serve` the windows default browser (Google chrome) opens up.

Is it possible to change the default browser for Ionic to FireFox, while keeping Google chrome as Windows' default browser? (I am thinking maybe there's a setting somewhere that tells Ionic which browser to open.)

Comment: It's probably an ionic question, not vscode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894533/how-do-i-set-ionic-serve-to-use-chrome-as-the-default-browser

Comment: I tried adding `"defaultBrowser": "firefox"` to the ionic.config.json file, but it still opens in Google chrome.

Comment: I never used ionic, so you should probably ask someone else.

Answer (score 1):

method 1. 
Click settings -> enter: default browser -> find: Open-in-browser:Default -> enter: Google Chrome .

method 2.
open settings.jon file and enter : "open-in-browser.default": "Google Chrome".

Answer (score 0):

In vscode open tasks.json file to update the browser

Comment: I guess you didn't read the whole post. This is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid doing.

Comment: In that case open tasks.json file in vscode and change the browser there.

Comment: Adding `"defaultBrowser": "firefox"` to tasks.json didn't work either.